# What is the meaning of "in" in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm learning Swift, and want to make sure I know what each part of my code does, even if it works.  I can't figure out precisely what "in" does here, even though the function breaks if I remove it.

```
session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in
...
```

The rest of the code isn't really relevant - just wondering what "in" does.

Thanks!

Comment: Comment rather than answer since it's not really answering what you're looking for, but this: { (x, y) in x + y } is meant to be read as something like "a closure that takes as inputs the values for the variables x and y in the expression x + y", which is where the "in" comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is part of swift's [closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) syntax. Because the parameters and a return type of a closure are inside the curly braces `in` is used to separate them from the body.

Answer (score 1):

Go read [the book](https://itunes.apple.com/au/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11), it's all in there:

> Use `in` to separate the arguments and return type from the body.